# How would I control multiple solenoid locks?

Tags: pwm, relay, servo

I would like to control 16 separate [solenoid locks](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Adafruit-Lock-style-Solenoid-12VDC-ADA1512/dp/B01GQFUQ06/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1504542893&sr=1-1&keywords=12v%20solenoid%20lock) using PWM (It is not imperative that the lock is 12V, it could be 6V for example).
The PWM source is this [16-channel servo driver](https://www.adafruit.com/product/815) from Adafuit. Is this possible?

I will only ever be driving one solenoid lock at a time. If it's not possible to do using the servo driver, I would like suggestions on how I could go about controlling all 16 locks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It managed to do it. I needed a MOSFET to switch enough current and a flyback diode to protect the transistor.

Answer (score 1):

PWM and solenoids, hmm doesn't sound like a good idea.

The solenoids you refers to are either on or off, why do you want a half locked/open lock?

I would propose 16 relays with driver circuits since the Raspberry Pi can only drive 16mA per GPIO and and not exceeding a total for all GPIO of 50mA.

Comment: I guess my question is: Is there a way I can set the PWM to give a basically always-on/100% duty cycle that mimics a DC signal?
The board is very easy to use and program, so I want to keep using it if possible to drive my locks.

Comment: Yes of course 100% = On and 0% = Off. but it can only control 5V/25mA per port and the datasheet for the solenoid mention 12V/500mA per Solenoid. And be aware that the PWM board has no fly back diode protection.